# Most frequent element in a sequence using arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, frequency

I'm doing an online course on "Programming, Data Structure & Algorithm". I've been given an assignment to "find the most frequent element in a sequence using arrays in C (with some constraints)". They've also provided some test-cases to verify the correctness of the program. But I think I'm wrong somewhere.

Here's the complete question from my online course.

> INPUT
>
> Input contains two lines. First line in the input indicates N,
> the number of integers in the sequence. Second line contains N
> integers, separated by white space.
>
> OUTPUT
>
> Element with the maximum frequency. If two numbers have the
> same highest frequency, print the number that appears first in the
> sequence.
>
> CONSTRAINTS
>
> 1 <= N <= 10000
>
> The integers will be in the range
>
> [-100,100].

And here's the test cases.

Test Case 1

Input:

```
5
1 2 1 3 1
```

Output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
6
7 7 -2 3 1 1
```

Output:

```
7
```

And here's the code that I've written.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter[201] = {0}, n, i, input, maximum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input < -100 && input < 100)
            ++counter[input];
    }
    maximum = counter[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 201; i++) {
        if (counter[i] > maximum) {
            maximum = counter[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", maximum);

    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me where I'm wrong. Thank you.

EDIT:

I've modified the code, as suggested by @zoska. Here's the working code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter[201] = {0}, n, i, input, maximum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input < 100 && input > 0)
            ++counter[input + 100];
        else
            ++counter[input];
    }
    maximum = counter[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
        if (counter[i] > maximum) {
            maximum = i - 100;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", maximum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if your input is negative, you'll be accessing array with negative index, which is out of bounds !!

Comment: I see *many* problems. Have you even tried to do some tracing/debugging?

Comment: Sadly, I use Linux TUI and I don't know how to debug from command line. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: @ASRM: learn it. your code is littered with bugs.

Comment: I'll learn it soon but for now I just have to complete the assignment. So, I'm searching for a better/quick solution. Please help me.

Comment: No, because you won't learn anything from it. That supposed to be the whole point of the assignment.

Comment: @ASRM: look at the test `if (input < -100 && input < 100)`. There is something reeeeally wrong here.
`

Comment: Give an example of input/output that your code gets/gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to problem pointed out by Paul R is:

You are printing maximum occurrences of number, not the number itself.

You're going to need another variable, which will store the number with maximum occurences. Like :

```
maximum = count[0];
int number = -100;
for (i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
    if (counter[i] > maximum) {
        maximum = counter[i];
        number = i - 100;
    }
}
printf("number %d has maximum occurences: %d", number, maximum);
```

Also you should iterate through an array from 0 to size-1:
So in all cases of your loops it should be :

```
for(i = 0; i < 201; i++)
```

Otherwise you won't be using count[0] and you will only have a range of -99...100.

Comment: Thanks @zoska. This helped me complete the assignment. I've edited the question. The question now includes the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter[201] = {0}, n, i, input, maximum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input >= -100 && input <= 100)
            ++counter[input + 100];
    }
    maximum = counter[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
        if (counter[i] >= maximum) {
        index = i;
        maximum = counter[i];
        }
    }
    printf("number %d occured %d times\n", index-100, maximum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer checking in one loop itself for the maximum value just so that the first number is returned if i have more than one element with maximum number of occurances.
FInd the code as:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,input;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int count[201] ={0};
    int max=0,found=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&input);
        count[input+100]++;
        if(max<count[input+100])
     {
            max= count[input+100];
            found=input;
     }
    }
    printf("%d",found);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

But, there is also one condition that if the number of occurance are same for two numbers then the number which appers first in sequence should appear.